# PHP doesn't give me error when I use a variable name without dollar sign

Tags: php

I am having the following code in a php web page:

```
  if (bInserted) echo "abc";
```

I would expect PHP to give me a syntax error since I forget to add the dollar sign before the variable name. Howver, the page doesn't produce any errors. Instead, it even echoes the "abc" string. I am not really able to understand this.

Comment: Could you show the code of your page?

Comment: It should generate a PHP notice (but they may be supressed). Check your logs.

Answer (score 5):

Your `bInserted` is interpreted as a `constant` and, since is not defined (I presume), it is then treated as the string `"bInserted"`, which evaluates to `true` hence your `"abc"` is printed.

Anyway, such implicit conversion from constant to string should raise a notice, see [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php).

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name
>   of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (CONSTANT
>   vs "CONSTANT"). An error of level E_NOTICE will be issued when this
>   happens.

If you really do not see any message, nor on screen nor in the logs, make sure you have set the correct [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level, you could for example try

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And, by the way, `E_ALL` is a defined constant in this case!

Comment: It should produce `notice` so write something about enabling errors reporting ;)

Comment: Right! Will do it now :)

Comment: Than would be an option too :)